# Can I use AngularJS Material's md-autocomplete with multiple values?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am in reference to AngularJS Material's **`md-autocomplete`**. See [here for documentation.](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete)

I am new to Angular Material and I need a multiple value autocomplete (somewhat like the **Tags** control of Stackoverflow).

Is this possible with AngularJS Material's `md-autocomplete`?

Here is what I have attempted:

```js
$scope.advertisement.languages = [];

$scope.chooseLanguages = function (input) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    languageService.languages(input, function (languages) {
        deferred.resolve(languages);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

```html
<md-autocomplete
  md-no-cache="false"
  md-min-length="3"
  md-selected-item="advertisement.languages"
  md-search-text="searchLanguage"
  md-items="language in chooseLanguages(searchLanguage)"
  md-item-text="language.description"
  placeholder="spoken languages?">
  <span ng-repeat="lang in advertisement.languages" md-highlight-text="lang">{{lang.description}}</span>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Can someone please advise on what is wrong with my attempt to get the autocomplete to work with multiple selected values?

Comment: Hi @nitin! I have tried to get the md-autocomplete to work with multiple values to no avail... Can you please advise?

Comment: Also: what is the separator to be used bewteen the multiple values? And from where can I push the results in the array?

Comment: @nitin I definitely got stuck there... Can you please confirm that the md-autocomplete allows multiple values?

Comment: OK. Is there any plan to have it deal with mutliple values out of the box?

Comment: @nitin only 1 YEAR later, the link's content is already broken. This is why external links are bad and not really welcomed at stackoverflow :|

Comment: use [md-chips](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips).